# Covering space of simplicial complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Is there a reference that discusses covering spaces of (abstract) simplicial complexes?

Is there an alternate definition of covering spaces for (abstract) simplicial complexes? The traditional definition contains many terms like “open sets” and “continuous map”, “homeomorphism” which is a bit awkward in a discrete setting.

Ideally, I am looking for a definition directed towards discrete abstract simplicial complexes without going into geometric realization.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The appendix I of Gabriel-Zisman's "Calculus of Fractions and Homotopy Theory" deals with coverings of simplicial sets and relates it to the usual notion of covering for the geometric realization, though the definition itself *doesn't* mention the geometric realization. Srinivas' "Algebraic K theory" mentions it too in thm A.48